# Perl module to transform string number 2.4E+04 to number

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm parsing a file that contains few numbers noted as 2.4E+04.

I found the module [Data::Str2Num](http://search.cpan.org/~softdia/Data-Str2Num-0.07/lib/Data/Str2Num.pm) that fits on my needs unfortunately Activeperl doesn't have it compiled to 5.16, only for 5.8 and I'm bounded to use 5.16 from Activeperl as it is the exact same version for production (I cannot use anything outside the ppm).

Is there any module like [Data::Str2Num](http://search.cpan.org/~softdia/Data-Str2Num-0.07/lib/Data/Str2Num.pm) that does the same in the newer versions?

**UPDATE:**

Inside a script you can do `my $value = "2.4E+04" + 0;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Evaluate it in a numeric context:

```
perl -e 'print "2.4E+04" + 0;'
24000
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tested and really works, just need to add, Doh!